# OverlayEntry listviewbuilder does not update with setstate in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, setstate

So I am implementing a search function that has a text form field and an overlay entry to display the results. Whenever the text form changes, the filter function is called which should theoretically update the listview in the overlay entry. Strangely, when I filter the list source data, I don't even need to call setstate in order for it to update, however, if I want to introduce an asynchronous method call before I update the data, the list will update properly the next time I press on the keyboard (as if its one step behind on filtering every time). However, if I hot reload everything appears fine.

I want the overlay entry to update on time but I can't seem to get it.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geocoding/geocoding.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:app/Databases/college_data.dart';
import 'package:app/Utilities/point_network_helper.dart';
import 'package:app/Widgets/Search_location_container.dart';
import 'package:app/Utilities/app_text_style.dart';

class LocationOverlay extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function setLocation;
  final LatLng? initialLocationCoordinates;
  final String? initalLocation;
  LocationOverlay(
      {Key? key,
      required this.setLocation,
      this.initalLocation,
      this.initialLocationCoordinates})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LocationOverlayState createState() => _LocationOverlayState();
}

class _LocationOverlayState extends State<LocationOverlay> {
  final FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();
  OverlayEntry? _overlayEntry;
  final LayerLink _layerLink = LayerLink();
  List<SearchLocationContainer> _allLocations = [];
  List<SearchLocationContainer> _selectedLocations = [];
  late TextEditingController fieldController;
  LatLng? _currentLocationCoordinate;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _focusNode.addListener(() {
      if (_focusNode.hasFocus) {
        this._overlayEntry = this._createOverlayEntry();
        Overlay.of(context)!.insert(this._overlayEntry!);
      } else {
        this._overlayEntry!.remove();
      }
    });
    fieldController = TextEditingController(text: widget.initalLocation ?? "");
    formLocationContainers();
  }

  void selectLocation(String location, LatLng coordinate) {
    _focusNode.unfocus();
    fieldController.text = location;
    _currentLocationCoordinate = coordinate;
    widget.setLocation(coordinate, fieldController.text);
    _runFilter(location);
  }

  void formLocationContainers() {
    StaticDataMap.forEach((location, coordinate) {
      _allLocations.add(SearchLocationContainer(
          location: location,
          coordinate: coordinate,
          selectLocation: selectLocation));
    });
    _selectedLocations = _allLocations;
  }

  void _runFilter(String enteredKeyword) async {
    if (enteredKeyword.isEmpty) {
      // I want it to use this
      setState(() {
      _selectedLocations = _allLocations;
      }
      // but this also works for some reason
      _selectedLocations = _allLocations;
      
    } else {
      List<SearchLocationContainer> results = [];
      results = _allLocations
          .where((location) => location.getLocation
              .toLowerCase()
              .contains(enteredKeyword.toLowerCase()))
              .toList();
      print("update");
      _getOtherLocations(enteredKeyword, results);
    }
  }

  Future<void> _getOtherLocations(
      String keyword, List<SearchLocationContainer> initialVals) async {
    List<Location> locations =
        await PointNetworkHelper().getPointFromAddress(keyword);

    List<SearchLocationContainer> newContainers = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      newContainers.add(SearchLocationContainer(
          location: locations[i].timestamp.toString(),
          coordinate: LatLng(locations[i].latitude, locations[i].longitude),
          selectLocation: selectLocation));
    }
    // same issue here, setstate does nothing to change the behavior
    setState(() {
         _selectedLocations = initialVals;
         _selectedLocations.addAll(newContainers);

    }
    // this will do the same thing
    _selectedLocations = initialVals;
    _selectedLocations.addAll(newContainers);

  }

  OverlayEntry _createOverlayEntry() {
    RenderObject? renderBox = context.findRenderObject();
    var size = renderBox!.paintBounds;

    return OverlayEntry(
    builder: (context) => Positioned(
          width: size.width,
          child: CompositedTransformFollower(
            key: UniqueKey(),
            link: _layerLink,
            showWhenUnlinked: false,
            offset: Offset(0.0, size.height - 15),
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
              constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 200),
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(15),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(15)),
              ),
              child: Material(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                child: ListView.separated(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return SizedBox(
                      child: _selectedLocations[index],
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .8,
                    );
                  },
                  separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return SizedBox(
                      height: 8,
                    );
                  },
                  itemCount: _selectedLocations.length,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CompositedTransformTarget(
      link: _layerLink,
      child: TextFormField(
          controller: fieldController,
          focusNode: _focusNode,
          autocorrect: false,
          enableSuggestions: false,
          onTap: () {
            if (fieldController.text == "") {
              _runFilter("");
            }
          },
          keyboardType: TextInputType.streetAddress,
          cursorColor: Colors.black,
          onChanged: (value) {
            _runFilter(value);
          },
          onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
            _runFilter(value);
            _focusNode.unfocus();
          },
       ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: got any solution?